# Firebase - why null is deleted in the tree?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I started using Firebase and Im still learning. I have trouble understanding why Firebase literally deletes null value from the tree.

In my understanding its harder to predict the data structure without having a null value in the tree. For example "current item" indicator.

I cant save the null property in the console.

So what are the benefits of not-saving null value in Firebase?

Comment: Firebase Database has no concept of a null, undefined or blank values. For every key, you must have a value. i.e. keys cannot exist without values. Also, you should not need to predict the data structure as in general you would know what it is since you created it or at least have some parameters of what keys should exist.  When data is written and a key doesn't exist, it's created so why do you need to put a null value in a database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The realtime nature of the Realtime Database makes this a desirable feature. Imagine, for instance, that I'm listening to a path in the tree like `path/to/a/val`:

```
firebase.database().ref('path/to/a/val').on('value', snap => {
  console.log(snap.val());
});
```

If `null` and deleted were treated differently, how should this behave if I set the value first to `null` and then delete it? Should the listener fire twice? Also, what happens if it goes from deleted, to null, and back to having a value?

By not differentiating between null values and undefined ones, the Realtime Database simplifies the conceptual model of data handling significantly.

If you strongly desire this kind of handling, [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/) has a document-oriented model that *does* allow for `null` values in fields of documents. Give it a look!